# Why are the microstates of a harmonic oscillator considered equally probable, when the particle spends more time at locations of zero momentum?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, probability, phase-space

Introductory statistical mechanics for a microcanonical ensemble (a.k.a. constant energy, no exchange of heat or work with environment) claims that all microstates in the momentum–location phase space are equally probable to occur.

But for a harmonic oscillator, the particle is more likely to be found at points of lower momentum, because the particle spends more time in those locations.

Here is an excerpt from Chapter 5 of Greiner’s *Thermodynamics and Statistical Mechanics* showing the example of the microstates in phase space of a 1D harmonic oscillator:

[image: Excerpt from Greiner]

It seems like common sense that those microstates have a **differing** probability of occurrence than each other, because the probability of finding the particle at the various locations is not equal.

Here is an excerpt from Chapter 2 of Griffith’s *Introduction to
Quantum Mechanics* showing this distribution:

[image: Excerpt from Griffith]

What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the fact that there are more low-momentum states than high-momentum states. Therefore you are still more likely to observe a low momentum, although all states are equally probable. It’s for the same reason that a twenty-sided die is less likely to land on non-prime number even when it’s perfectly fair.

If you take your Figure 5.1, let $ΔE$ go towards $0$, and collapse all the area on the $q$ axis, you will get a similar distribution as in your Figure 2.7.

Comment: Aha, so in other words, you're saying that: even though the particle's velocity through q-space changes in time, and thus the particle "loiters"/"lingers" at some locations longer than others, the particle's velocity through p-q-space (aka "phase space") is constant in time, thus the particle's location in p-q-space does NOT "loiter" or "linger" at any locations in p-q-space compared to other locations in p-q-space.  That makes sense.

Comment: It would also mean that the particle visits every location of phase space during each "orbit" of phase space.... And for chaotic systems (such as this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U39RMUzCjiU) the system randomly visits each state with equal time-statistics.   Is there any proof of these ideas?  Without a proof I could easily be convinced by somebody claiming to have a simple mechanical device (such as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U39RMUzCjiU) that spends more time in particular states than others.

Comment: In other words, I could easily be convinced by somebody claiming to have a simple chaotic device (such as the double pendulum device in the video I posted above) that spends less time in some microstates because they are "less accessible" than other microstates -- where "less accessible" means the device has to be in a rare orientation to gain entrance to the less accessible microstates.   Thoughts, anyone?

Comment: That concept/idea/hypothesis is called *ergodicity* and is a subject on its own. For Hamiltonian systems (such as the double pendulum), you may also want to have a look at Liouville’s theorem. Mind that chaotic systems are not random in the sense that you appear to be using.

Comment: Aha, thank you very much!  You've turned me onto the mainstream considerations of this topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_hypothesis.   Again, much thanks.

Comment: Ok, so my original question was: Is it true that all microstates of a microcanonical system are "visited" equally frequently in time?  Louiville's theorem doesn't answer that question -- it seems that Louiville's theorem proves incompressibility of phase space, but that's not exactly the question posed here.  This article on ergodicity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_hypothesis) appears to respond to my question with an answer: No, for some systems, the microstates are not visited equally.  Thus the fundamental assumption of statistical mechanics is violated for some systems.